# Как измерить длину массива Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня есть interface IAnswers в котором описан тип answers как массив

```
export interface IAnswers {
    answers: [{_id: string, answerAuthor: string, answer: string}]
}
```

Но когда в коде я пытаюсь получить доступ к answers.length, Typescript выдаёт ошибку.
Свойство "length" не существует в типе "IAnswers".

Как решить эту проблему? И от чего она происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не правильно определен интерфейс, надо вот так

```
export interface IAnswers {
    answers: {_id: string, answerAuthor: string, answer: string}[];
}
```

или

```
export interface IAnswers {
    answers: IAnswer[];
}

export interface IAnswer {
    _id: string; answerAuthor: string; answer: string;
}
```